# how can i get my soft body sim to look less cloth like?

Tags: rigid-body-simulation, soft-body

so, this is a nutsack, and id like the nuts to not look like theyre empty and made of cloth, i'd like it to be much firmer and just jiggly, but nothing i do achieves that result. here is a video of what im talking about:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/uMGGp.jpg
these are my settings:

[image]

[image]

i have the top few verts as my vertex group for pinning

Comment: did you try to put some icospheres with collisions in it and animate them a bit?

Comment: how would i apply those to the sack though